# Ткани трудно удаляют жиры и масло — корректно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Однако у акриловых тканей есть и свои недостатки.
>
> Могут растянуться при стирке.
> Эти ткани легко впитывают жиры и масло, и их трудно удаляют. Поэтому акрил редко используется самостоятельно.

*Ткани трудно удаляют жиры и масло* — корректно ли так сказать?
Или здесь имеется в виду "трудно удаляют" (как пример неопределенно-личного предложения)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше сказать: и их трудно удалить/ которые удаляются с трудом.
Понятно, что ткань сама пятен не удаляет. А вот «С таких тканей удалить следы жира и масла довольно трудно» — вполне нормальное предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Так сказать *нельзя* (ткань пассивна в отношении действия "удаления"), но при необходимости можно сохранить "ткани" в роли подлежащего:

> Эти ткани плохо *поддаются удалению* [или "*очистке от*"] жировых (масляных) пятен.